# Adding custom function to Bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, plugins, twitter-bootstrap, parameter-passing, prototype

I've recently run across a situation in which I'd like to change Bootstrap's default behavior at a fundamental level.  I'd like to add a custom method to the `Modal` class so that a custom method may be called like any other stock `Modal` method:

```
$('#my-modal').modal('myMethod', myParameter);
```

I have this working by adding a function to the `Modal`'s constructor:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.myMethod = function (myParameter) {
  ...
}
```

However, the `myParameter` variable is not being passed.  How do I access/pass `myParameter` to a custom Bootstrap method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this, although unfortunately it involves changes to the Bootstrap source.  The piece of code that does the actual method calling is this:

```
$.fn.modal = function (option) {
  return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this)
      , data = $this.data('modal')
      , options = $.extend({}, $.fn.modal.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
    if (!data) $this.data('modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
    if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    else if (options.show) data.show()
  })
}
```

To change this, the 7th line (line 206 in the [source code](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/839b0c893fe2f2760682bee9dc49d5fa0b9c0412/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L206)) should be modified to pass any additional parameters that were originally passed to the enclosing function.  In addition, the original arguments must be given to each iteration of jQuery's `.each()` function.  Here's the working code:

```
$.fn.modal = function (option) {
  return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this)
      , data = $this.data('modal')
      , options = $.extend({}, $.fn.modal.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
    if (!data) $this.data('modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
    if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].apply($this.data('modal'), Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); // pass the parameters on
    else if (options.show) data.show()
  }, arguments) // execute each iteration with the original parameters
}
```

I'm still experimenting to make sure this change doesn't create any undesirable side effects, but so far, everything works as expected.  Any more elegant solutions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of you doing this as-is. [The code](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/839b0c893fe2f2760682bee9dc49d5fa0b9c0412/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L206) Model uses to call a function does not take parameters into consideration;

```
  $.fn.modal = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('modal')
        , options = $.extend({}, $.fn.modal.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      if (!data) $this.data('modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]() // <-- here
      else if (options.show) data.show()
    })
  }
```

Your best bet would be to add a method to `$.fn`, and then retrieve the `Model` instance via `$(this).data('modal')`, as that's where Bootstrap stores the instance;

```
$.fn.foo = function (param) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var model = $(this).data('modal');

        // blah blah blah
    });
}
```